# How to get all scheduled or executing OperationQueues and cancel it

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have a scenario where i want to cancel all the NSOperationQueue which is scheduled or started from multiple ViewController.

Thanks in advance

Comment: NSOperationQueue has a method called `cancelAllOperations`

Comment: I dont have reference of NSOperationQueue

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at an example

```
let queue = OperationQueue()

let op = BlockOperation {
    print("Operation 1 is executing")
}

let op2 = BlockOperation {
    print("Operation 2 is executing")
}

queue.addOperation(op)
queue.addOperation(op2)
```

If you run this code you will get the result

```
Operation 1 is executing
Operation 2 is executing
```

After adding these two `BlockOperation`s or `Operation`s you can cancel them with

```
queue.cancelAllOperations()
```

You can get a list of operations in the queue

```
print(queue.operations)
```

and you would get

```
[
 <NSBlockOperation 0x600000043e40 isFinished=YES isReady=YES isCancelled=NO isExecuting=NO>, 
 <NSBlockOperation 0x600000045e50 isFinished=YES isReady=YES isCancelled=NO isExecuting=NO>
]
```

So you can see both finished and were not canceled, however if we were to cancel them with `queue.cancelAllOperations()` we would get

```
[
 <NSBlockOperation 0x600000043e40 isFinished=YES isReady=YES isCancelled=YES isExecuting=NO>, 
 <NSBlockOperation 0x600000045e50 isFinished=YES isReady=YES isCancelled=YES isExecuting=NO>
]
```